# Honda Accord 2002, Vehicle a/c climate button control, change with missing buttons

Tags: honda, ac, accord, climate-control

So I was wondering if somehow I can change the climate mode with missing buttons.

So long story short, I hit my AC thing and it caused two a/c buttons to break, none of my climate mode buttons work. I turn my car on and it's set on a/c defroster.

Is there a way I can change the mode setting without having to buy a new one? Or am I screwed and need to replace it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Sounds like you need to replace it.